# Is Russel's Teapot an allegory?

Tags: terminology

For some reason I just had this question pop into my mind. It seems reasonable to treat Russel's teapot as an allegory.

One definition that might indicate this is "the expression by means of symbolic fictional figures and actions of truths or generalizations about human existence a writer known for his use of allegory; also : an instance (as in a story or painting) of such expression The poem is an allegory of love and jealousy ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/allegory))."

Comment: Isn't this a question for English SE? They already have [What is the difference between “metaphorical”, “allegorical”, and “figurative”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23588/what-is-the-difference-between-metaphorical-allegorical-and-figurative)

Comment: It could be, however allegories are philosophical tools.

Comment: It wouldn't be my idea of an allegory. although if it was turned into teaching story about someone who believed in orbiting teapots and got their comeuppance it would become one.

Comment: @Daniel Goldman. Exactly so. Think of Plato's allegory of the Cave in Republic, VI - even if no-one quite knows what Plato intends !

Comment: Is the teapot example an analogy rather than an allegory as Russell uses it? As belief in the non-evidential teapot is to reasonable  belief, so is belief in a non-evidential God.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a thought experiment that is supposed to convey a deeper meaning. That being we can't prove (which is a problematic term in empirical science because of the way it is used in mathematics is not the same) anything about empirical reality, especially that which we have no evidence for. It's along the lines of "absence of evidence isn't evidence of absence". Meaning just because we don't have evidence for something existing doesn't mean it doesn't exist.

We can't prove Russell's teapot doesn't exist (maybe we can now due to developments in astronomical observational techniques), we can't prove we weren't created 30 seconds ago with all of our memories implanted, we can't prove we aren't in a simulation, and so on. Russell and those after him use this type of example usually in the frame of metaphysical debates about deities. If there is no evidence for Russell's teapot existing why believe it does? And similarly, if there is the same amount of empirical evidence for a deity existing, why believe one does? Those who have highly subjective or personal experience or reasons for believing in deities would make claims to the contrary. However, the analogy is applicable to anything we believe or think is the case about perceptual reality. So the whole issue can be a bit vague and it depends upon what axioms you start with and what initial assumptions you make about what "reality" is. If people can't agree on that starting point, any further interlocution will be unproductive.